# Sql logshipping restore delay

Tags: sql-server

I have a production database which logships to a reporting db but the restore seems to be happening only once in 24 hours . The job is set to run every 15 mins but it seems that nothing gets restored and the message says "backup file skipped as the restore delay has not reached.". I tried to find the restore delay  with the query

Select  secondary_database, 
        restore_delay 
from    msdb.dbo.log_shipping_secondary_databases

but I can get anything related to that database.

1) Which server do I need to change the restore delay option
2) How to change the restore delay to 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  However, the query you mentioned only returns values when connected to the Secondary server in the Log Shipping configuration.  If you determine the restore delay needs to change, that must be done on the Primary server *(Right-click database -> Properties -> Transaction Log Shipping -> Click on the ... button to the right of the database listed -> Restore Transaction Log tab)*